# How to go back to home screen of Android Things on Raspberry Pi 3 from the foreground running app?

Tags: android

I am developing an **Android Things** application on **Raspberry Pi 3**. But once the app is installed, I cannot go back to the home screen of Android Things to get the ***ip address*** of the device to connect it to my computer.

I tried ***Esc*** key on the connected keyboard but it just restarts the app and when pressing it multiple times rapidly it shows a message with two options:

> app keeps stopping:
>   
> - Open app again
>   
> - Close app

But they also just restart the app again.

So is there a way to show the home screen again?

***Note***: The installed version of Android Things is DP 0.6.0

Comment: Your app *is* the home screen, once your app is installed. If you want the IP address, put it in your own UI somewhere, at least on `debug` builds.

Comment: @CommonsWare What if you have more than one app installed. How to switch between them?

Comment: "What if you have more than one app installed" -- only one can have the `IOT_LAUNCHER` `<intent-filter>` AFAIK. "How to switch between them?" -- for your own apps, you would need to have smarts to start them yourself. For production, you wouldn't want to show the standard Things home screen in most cases, so whatever you want from that home screen that end users would want you would re-implement somewhere in your own UI.

Comment: even when the app crash, start a new one... :(